# Call element from fragment in Adapter

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, adapter

My situation:
I have `Activity` with `Fragments`. In `Activity` I have `GridView` genereted by adapter. When I click on the element in `GridView` I call `onClickListener` in Adapter class. How can I call element from another fragment in this listener ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has provided a nice documentation on Communicating with Fragments.

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Deliver) out.

**EDIT**

when adding, add the fragment with tag..

```
MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment, "myfrag");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

and retrive it like this

```
MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("myfrag");
```